# how to check if an user input str value is equal to any str value in a list populated from pandas dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a simple interface where I input a string value, and the function has to check if that value is equal to any string value in my dataset column. if the input is equal to the column value the program returns that input. And if not the program raises a value error. But in my program even if I input the value that is in the column of my dataset, it still raises an error... help is needed, thank you in advance

```py
def str_input1(x):
    x_new = str(input())
    if x_new not in set(x.loc[:, column]):
        raise ValueError('error')
    else: 
        return x_new
```

Comment: Possible misleading _list_ word in title?

Comment: well yes, I tried it with a list, and turned it to a set, but it didn't work both times. I forgot to change the code

Comment: I mean title promises a _list_ then body text treats about a _dataset_.

Comment: I turned specific columns in my dataset to lists

Comment: Your question is not about Python's _lists_, it's about Pandas' _datasets_.

Comment: how can I edit that?

Comment: Maybe you can't. It seems you agree, so I'll try to edit it myself.